# single regex to capitalize first letter and replace dot

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Trying out with a regex for simple problem. My input string is

`firstname.ab`

And am trying to output it as,

`Firstname AB`

So the main aim is to capitalize the first letter of the string and replace the dot with space. So chose to write two regex to solve.

**First One :** To replace dot with space `/\./g`

**Second One :** To capitalize the first letter `/\b\w/g`

And my question is, Can we do both operation with a single regex ?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a callback function inside the `replace`:

```js
var str = 'firstname.ab';
 
var result = str.replace(/^([a-zA-Z])(.*)\.([^.]+)$/, function (match, grp1, grp2, grp3, offset, s) {
    return grp1.toUpperCase() + grp2 + " " + grp3.toUpperCase();
});
alert(result);
```

The `grp1`, `grp2` and `grp3` represent the capturing groups in the callback function. `grp1` is a leading letter (`[a-zA-Z]`). Then we capturing any number of character other than newline (`(.*)` - if you have linebreaks, use `[\s\S]*`). And then comes the literal dot `\.` that we do not capture since we want to replace it with a space. And lastly, the `([^.]+$)` regex will match and the capture all the remaining substring containing 1 or more characters other then a literal dot till the end.

We can use capturing groups to *re-build* the input string this way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your explanation. that makes your point clear :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var $input = $('#input'),
    value = $input.val(),
    value = value.split( '.' );

value[0] = value[0].charAt( 0 ).toUpperCase() + value[0].substr(1),
value[1] = value[1].toUpperCase(),
value = value.join( ' ' );

$input.val( value );

It would be much easier if you simply split the value, process the string in the array, and join them back.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="first.ab" id="input">
```